# Diffrential equation of an integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I read in a paper about a differential equation that I don't understand how. 
let $I(y) = \int_0^\infty  {g(x,\,y)f(x)dx} $ where $f(.)$ is an Probability Distribution Function and $g(.,\,.)$ is just a function of variables $x$ and $y$. Then we obtain
$$
\frac{{\partial I(y)}}{{\partial y}} = \frac{{\partial g(x,y)}}{{\partial y}} \times f(x)
$$
Can someone explaint why we can have above equation?
If $I(x,\,y) = \int_a^b  {g(x,\,y)f(x)dx} $ with any real number $a$ and $b$. Is the above diffrential equation still valid?

Comment: Your definition of $I$ has $x$ as a dummy variable on the right and independent on the left and therefore doesn't make any sense.

Comment: $f(.)$ doesn't consist of $y$ in its expression.

Comment: $f$ isn't a function of $y$ but I don't see what that has to do with my objection. You define $I$ as an integral **over** $x$ so $I$ **cannot** be a function of $x$.

Comment: OK. I understant your point. I will edit my question.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.  The left side $\dfrac{\partial I(y)}{\partial y}$ does not depend on $x$, but the right side does.  Perhaps you mean

$$ \dfrac{\partial I(y)}{\partial y} = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y} f(x)\ dx $$

which (under appropriate conditions) is true.

If that's not it, and this is a published paper, perhaps you could send us a link or reference and we could tell you what it's really saying.